# Defer, debounce or timeout an event

Tags: javascript, timeout, deferred, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have two events

```
cy.on('mousedown touchstart', 'node', function (event) {
  // start
});

cy.on('mouseover tapdragover', 'node', function (event) {
  // end
});
```

The problem is that the second event is almost immediately fired since the first event was fired when the mouse is being pressed on a node and the second is fired when the mouse is over a node.

Is it possible to `debounce` or `defer` the action? I know the syntax is `cytoscape.js`-specific, but I guess the regular possibilities of using `debounce` and `defer` apply.

I guess an easy solution would be to save a timestamp in the first event and check if `endTime - startTime > threshold` in the second event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use Lodash: `cy.on('evt1 evt2 ...', _.debounce( handler ))`